# Count number of jQuery $.get success responses

Tags: php, jquery, curl

I have a jQuery function that loads a PHP file (which gets a JSON response from an application) every 100ms. What I am trying to do is have two different counters, one which will increment every time a request is sent and another counter which will increment as soon as it gets a JSON response. At the moment I have the following which is not working, they are both just counting the number of requests being sent:-

**JQUERY**

```
$(function() {

    var MAXNUM = 9;
    var count = 0;
    var countSuccess = 0;

    function newAsyncRequest() {
        setTimeout(function() {

            newAsyncRequest();
            count++;

            $(".request").html(count);

             $.get('test.php', function(data) {
                countSuccess++;
                $( ".log" ).html(countSuccess);
             });

        }, 100);
    }

    newAsyncRequest();

});
```

**PHP**

```
require_once('scripts/php/controllers/curl.controller.php');

$postcode = 'LE11 5';
$postcode = rawurlencode($postcode);

$uri = 'http://192.168.1.110:8290/?pc='.$postcode; // Home

$response = CurlController::request($uri);
```

So my question is basically, how can I count the number of successful responses I am getting from .$get command?

Comment: How do you expect the two to differ? Unless the server throws an error, they will always be the same.

Comment: `$(".request").html(count);`?

Answer (score 0):

Need to print `count` to `.request`, you were using `countSuccess` in both the statements

```
$(function() {

    var MAXNUM = 9;
    var count = 0;
    var countSuccess = 0;

    function newAsyncRequest() {
        setTimeout(function() {

            newAsyncRequest();
            count++;

            $(".request").html(count);
            //need to print here

             $.get('test.php', function(data) {
                countSuccess++;
                $( ".log" ).html(countSuccess);
             });

        }, 100);
    }

    newAsyncRequest();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)'s `success` parameter. The function passed to this parameter will only run if an ajax request is successful.

```
$.ajax({
  url:"",
  type: "get",
  beforeSend: function(){ requestCounter++ },
  success: function(){ successCounter++ }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you defijning as a success?

The .get 'success' is that the server responded which it hopefully always will do.

If you are definign success as somthign working in the PHP script then in the PHP then in the jquery success function check what was returned in 'data' to see if it was succesful.

I generally return a Json encoded array with an element called 'result' that is either set to ture or false by the PHP and the jquery can simple act on that record.